# php href change variable same page without refreshing

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I'm trying to change variable with a bookmark link to **Div** the same page without refreshing.

```html
<a href="#" action="<? $aa=4; ?>" onclick="<? $aa=1; ?>document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" >ok1</a>
<a href="#" action="<? $aa=5; ?>" onclick="<? $aa=2; ?>document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" >ok2</a>
<a href="#" action="<? $aa=6; ?>" onclick="<? $aa=3; ?>document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" >ok3</a>

<div id="id01" class="w3-modal">
<span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" 
   class="w3-closebtn w3-padding-top">&times;</span>
<h2>Header</h2>

  <ul class="w3-pagination" style="width:100%;">
   <li><a href="#" class="tablink" onclick="openCity(event, 'First')">First</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" class="tablink" onclick="openCity(event, 'second')">second</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" class="tablink" onclick="openCity(event, 'third')">third</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div id="First" class="w3-container">
// for example 1
   <? echo $aa; ?> 
  </div>

  <div id="second" class="w3-container">
// for example 2
   <? echo $aa; ?> 
  </div>

 <div id="third" class="w3-container">
// for example 3
   <? echo $aa; ?> 
  </div>

</div>
```

I need get different values by clicking the above links.

Comment: why don't you use something like buttons instead?

Comment: It's a part of table list may more than a thousands links. Speed of href is better.

Answer (score 0):

if you really want the javascript to be executed within the href this is the way to do this:

`<a id="myLink" href="javascript:MyFunction();">link text</a>`

but this is better:

`<a id="myLink" href="#" onclick="MyFunction();return false;">link text</a>`

Why better? because return false will prevent browser from following the link

alternatively you could use jQuery or other similar framework to attach onclick handler by element's ID, this would be your the best:

`$('#myLink').click(function(){ MyFunction(); return false; });`